# Ruby - how to speed up looping through an ".each" array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, performance, each

I'm having these models and following lines in a method where I am trying to improve performance of the code.

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
end
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :locations
end
```

In the method:

```
locations_company = []

###
found_locations = Location.within(distance, origin: from_result.split(',')).order("distance ASC")
### 0.002659s

###
found_locations.each do |location|
  locations_company << location.company
end
### 45.972285s

###
companies = locations_company.uniq{|x| x.id}
### 0.033029s
```

The code has this functionality - first, grab all locations within a specified radius. Then, from each found row take the company and save it to the prepared array. This is the problematic part - the each loop takes 45 seconds to process.

And then from this newly created array remove duplicities.

I still wondering if there would be a better approach to solve this situation, but I am afraid I don't see it right now, so I'd like to ask you guys how I could speed up the `.each` looping with saving data to the array - is there a better method in ruby to grab some information from an object?

Thank you very much for your time, I am immersed in this problem the whole day, but still don't have a  more effective solution.

Comment: If you look at `found_locations` you'll notice that it's likely a query proxy, and not a coalesced result set. The `#each` is almost certainly not your bottleneck; you should properly profile your code to find the bottlenecks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about refactoring and improving performance of existing code, and should be on [codereview.se].

Answer (score 7):

The best way would be to not loop. Your end goal appears to be to find all the companies in the specified area.

```
found_locations = Location.within(distance, origin: from_result.split(',')).order("distance ASC")
companies = Company.where(id: found_locations.pluck(:company_id).uniq)
```

Comment: A `Company.distinct` instead `bleh.uniq` may be helpful, if supported by the db.

Comment: Company.distinct is not needed. If you leave off the uniq it just passes a larger array into the `WHERE id IN []` query. The database will only return one record per company even if the ids are included more than once in the array. I just personally don't like sending more information into the query than necessary and adding/removing `uniq` is not going to materially effect the performance.

Comment: Depending on if `found_locations` will actually be used or not in addition to the companies, you might take different variations on this. If you plan on using `found_locations` separately, then you can/should force it to an array with `to_a` and then change the logic in the next line to be `Company.where(id: found_locations.map(&:id).uniq)`. If you don't plan on using found_locations separately, then what I put there would be best as then you won't even create the `Location` objects and instead just pull the ids that you need.

Comment: Another [peachy-keen](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/peachy%20keen) answer!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the thing that takes all the time is not the `each`, but rather the query to the db.

The first line, although it builds the query does not really run it.

I believe that if you write the code as follows:

```
locations_company = []

found_locations = Location.within(distance, origin: from_result.split(',')).order("distance ASC")

### this line will take most of the time
found_locations = found_locations.to_a
###    

###
found_locations.each do |location|
  locations_company << location.company_id
end
### 

###
companies = locations_company.uniq{|x| x.id}
###
```

You'll see that the `each` will take a lot less time. You should look into optimizing the query.

---

As @AlexPeachey has commented below, `location.company` will also involve a query for each location in the list, since it is a relation. You might want to eagerly load the company by adding:

```
found_locations = Location.includes(:company).within(distance, origin: from_result.split(',')).order("distance ASC")
```

Comment: The query may well be slow, however the each will not be immediate with this approach because you are doing a query against the company table each time through the each loop. To avoid this, changing to `Location.includes(:company)` will load all of the companies required with just one additional query.

Comment: Thanks @AlexPeachey, I missed that part. Updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in the each, but in that the query only begins executing when you start iterating over it. `found_locations` is no the result of the query, it is a query builder that will execute the query once it is needed (such as when you start iterating the results).